# How to round a cell after user input in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

It should be a very simple function but I can't find anything that functions the way I need.
I want to have a cell where a number can be entered, then after its entered it is replaced by that number rounded to its nearest 0.25
For example:
I enter `5.26` into cell A1, after i press enter the cell now says `5.25`
This should only happen with cell A1, so if i enter `5.26` elsewhere it will stay as `5.26`
Any help? Thanks in advance and sorry if this a common question.

Comment: You  need to learn apps script. Take the 30 minute intro in [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieve by using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and [onEdit Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

Follow these steps to achieve the desired goal.

1. In your Google Sheet, go to **Tools** -> **Script editor**.
2. Delete any code in the script editor and paste code provided below.
3. Click **Save**.
4. Go back to your Google Sheet and type numbers in cell A1.
5. Press enter and wait the value to change.

**Code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var input = e.value;
  if(range.getA1Notation() == "A1" && !isNaN(input)){
    var number = (Math.round(input * 4) / 4).toFixed(2);
    range.setValue(number);
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

[image]

> Triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain
> event, like opening a document, occurs. In your case, we need to use
> onEdit since it  runs automatically when a user changes the value of
> any cell in a spreadsheet. Apps Script passes the
> triggered function an event object that contains information about the
> context in which the event occurred (usually named `e`).

In the demo above, I created a condition that will check if the edited cell is **A1** and if the inputted value is number. If both satisfy the condition, the script will calculate the value and use range.setValue() to change the value of A1.

### References:

- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Range.setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)
- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)